# On Error Goto: Multiple times

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using a macro to get infos from a website:

```
Sub get_prices()

Dim IE As Object
Dim URL As String
Dim cell As Range

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A2", Range("A1048576").End(xlUp))

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

For Each cell In rng.Cells
comeco:
    On Error GoTo pau:
    URL = Cells(1, 2) & cell.Text & "?utm_source=teste" & Rnd
    IE.Navigate (URL)
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.READYSTATE = 4
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

    Cells(cell.Row, 2) = Mid(IE.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Conteudo_ctl01_precoPorValue").innertext, 3)
    Cells(cell.Row, 2).Formula = _
                WorksheetFunction.Substitute(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Cells(cell.Row, 2), ".", ""), ",", ".")
Next

pau:
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
GoTo comeco:

End Sub
```

The problem is that from time to time, my Excel kind of "loses the IE object", and I get the error message "THE OBJECT IS REQUERIED" in the following line:
`Cells(cell.Row, 2) = Mid(IE.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Conteudo_ctl01_precoPorValue").innertext, 3)`

Normally, I just debug the code, and make a new line, like:
`Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`
and then I resume the macro.

Bud I'd like to make something more robust, something that everytime an error occurs, it closes the IE and then reopen it.

I'm trying to use
`on error goto`
But it only works the first time a error occurs, if it happens again it wont go to the error section.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where is the `On Error Goto ...` statement?  If it's only catching the error the first time, it may be that the `Resume` statement isn't set up correctly.

Comment: @Blackhawk, I put 
`comeco:`
`On Error Goto pau:` in the beggining, and them at the end of the code I did it:
`pau: IE.Quit
`Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`
`goto: comeco`

Comment: Remove the `comeco:` and replace `goto: comeco` with `Resume`.  Resume retries the line where the error occurred.  If you do not use `Resume`, VBA assumes you are still in the process of handling the error - see [this msdn page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141571) for details.

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the code you actually tried (rather than explaining it in prose form in comments!).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Hello Jean, sorry I didnt put my actual code there, but since it was not working, I thought that someone could give me some ideas, but sure I should have posted the code so you can check where it is wrong. I edited my question, now my code is there.

Comment: @Blackhawk You just changed my life! Haha I didn't know about the `Resume`, I've been looking for a way to do that for a long time, now the code is working fine, I'll try for a few days and see is it's working flawlessly! Thank you very much!

Comment: @EVERYONE lesson learned, from now on I'll always post my whole code! Thank you

Comment: @FabioRebelo was `Resume` was the solution to your problem? If so, I can split my comment off and make it an answer for acceptance so that anyone who is running into the same problem can find that solution.

Comment: @Blackhawk Sure, it was exactly what I was looking for.
I'd appreciate if you do that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are trying to add error handling to catch the missing InternetExplorer instance, try the following.  Add On Error statements to your code just before and just after the offending line.

```
On Error Goto IE_missing   'This changes error handling from the default popup error message to instead direct VBA to jump to the IE_missing label and try the code there.
Cells(cell.Row, 2) = Mid(IE.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Conteudo_ctl01_precoPorValue").innertext, 3)
On Error Goto 0   'This resets the error handling back to the default so you don't accidentally catch errors in other parts of the code
```

And then place a section at the end of your code like so:

```
    Exit Sub  'This keeps the rest of the Sub's code from accidentally running down into the error section.

IE_missing:   'When the specific line above errors, VBA directs execution here
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
    Resume    'Now that the IE instance has been set again, retry the offending line of code
```

Answer (score 2):

you lose the IE window when you call navigate.  I overcame this by calling navigate then passing the url I was looking for to the function below and calling it like this

```
'this is where you create your URL
URL = Cells(1, kit.Column + i) & kit.Text & "?utm_source=teste" & Rnd
'navigate to the page
IE.Navigate (URL)
'get the page we just went to
Set IE = GetWebPage(URL)






''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Desc: The Function gets the Internet Explorer window that has the current
'   URL from the sURL Parameter.  The Function Timesout after 30 seconds
'Input parameters:
    'String sURL - The URL to look for
'Output parameters:
    'InternetExplorer ie - the Internet Explorer window holding the webpage
'Result: returns the the Internet Explorer window holding the webpage
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetWebPage(sUrl As String) As InternetExplorer
Dim winShell As Shell
Dim dt As Date
dt = DateAdd("s", 300, DateTime.Now)

Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Do While dt > DateTime.Now
    Set winShell = New Shell
    'loop through the windows and check the internet explorer windows
    For Each ie In winShell.Windows
    If ie.LocationURL = sUrl Then

    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Silent = True
        Set GetWebPage = ie

        Do While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
        Loop
        Exit Do

    Set winShell = Nothing
    End If
    Next ie
    Set winShell = Nothing
    DoEvents
Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try your code soon!
Just have to figure out something, when I try to run it i get a error:
Compile error: User-defined type not defined.
in the `Function GetWebPage(sUrl As String) As InternetExplorer`, line.

Do you know if I have to enable a library for it?
One more question, do you know WHY this problem happens when I use navigate?

Comment: you need to add a reference to Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why Excel "kind of loses the IE object", so I hesitate to give this answer.

Why not add a check before the call to make sure the IE object is not null:

```
If IE Is Nothing Then
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
End If
Cells(kit.Row, kit.Column + i) = Mid(IE.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Conteudo_ctl01_precoPorValue").innertext, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you Richard, though I'm not using your answer in this code, it gave me a few new ideas for others problems that I'm having with others macros, I've never thought about checking if a variable is nothing!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mid(IE.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Conteudo_ctl01_precoPorValue").innertext, 3 , ***xx***)

there must be xx number for mid

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, sedat! This is not really an answer. Please provide some explanations...